# Dynamically add Text Field and drop-down in form on button click event in wicket.?

Tags: java, wicket

i am trying to add Text Field and Drop Down box in the form on button click event using wicket framework. using JavaScript to generate Text Field and drop-down dynamically with unique wicket:id on html page.at java page how can i store the values of dynamically generated Text Field in a string type array at event of submit button.

Java Script at HTML to generate Text Field and Drop-Down Box

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var intTextBox=0; 
function f()
{

   intTextBox = intTextBox + 1; 
  var testdiv = document.getElementById('testdiv'); 
  var testdiv1 = document.getElementById('testdiv1'); 
  var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var newTBDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
  var data0="A";
  var data1="B";
  var data2="C";
  var data3="D";
  var data4="E";
  var data5="F";

newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox); 
newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Field "+intTextBox+":<input type='text' wicket:id='id"+intTextBox + "' size='"+50+"' maxlength='"+100+"''/>"; 
newTBDiv1.innerHTML = "<select wicket:id='dropdownid"+intTextBox+"' style=width:10em;> <option>"+data0+"</option> <option>"+data1+"</option> <option>"+data2+"</option> <option>"+data3+"</option> <option>"+data4+"</option> <option>"+data5+"</option></select>"; 
testdiv.appendChild(newTBDiv); 
testdiv1.appendChild(newTBDiv1);
return true;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

in Java file i am trying to do

```
  String textFielddata[] = new String[intTextfieldcount];
  String textFieldtype[] = new String[intTextfieldcount];
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<intTextfieldcount;i++)
            {
                count=count+1;

                form.add(new TextField<String>"id"+count).setRequired(true));
                form.add(new new DropDownChoice<String>("dropdownid"+count).setRequired(true));
                //downControl.add(new TextField<String>("id"+count,new PropertyModel<String>(this,"id"+count))).setOutputMarkupId(true);
                textFielddata[i]=form.getDefaultModelObjectAsString("id"+count);
                textFieldtype[i]=form.getDefaultModelObjectAsString("dropdownid"+count);
System.out.println(textFielddata[i]);
System.out.println(textFieldtype[i]);
            }
```

textFieldData[] and textFieldtype[] is string type array,
inttextfieldcount is integer type and its value is equal to number of dynamically generated Text Field and drop-down box

output: 
id1
dropdownid1

id2
dropdownid2

**The Problem is** it is not showing the data from dynamically generated Text Field and select value of Drop-Down box

or suggest me any other way in Wicket to implement this functionality without using JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the dropdown and the textfield normally and just make them hidden initially. Then use the button clicked event handler to show the components via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
   final MarkupContainer rowPanel = new WebMarkupContainer("rowPanel");
 rowPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);

 form.add(rowPanel);
```

// List all rows

```
 ArrayList rows = new ArrayList(2);
 rows.add(new String());
 rows.add(new String());
 final ListView lv = new ListView("rows", rows) {



 @Override
   protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
     int index = item.getIndex() + 1;
     item.add(new Label("index", index + "."));

     TextField text = new TextField("text", item.getModel()));
     item.add(text);
   }
 };
 rowPanel.add(lv);

 AjaxSubmitLink addLink = new AjaxSubmitLink("addRow", form) {
   @Override
   public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
     lv.getModelObject().add(new String());
     if (target != null)
       target.addComponent(rowPanel);
   }
 };
 addLink.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
 rowPanel.add(addLink);
```

Comment: Working code for what? I don't see this answer as the correct one for this question. If it's the code you're using, please, edit the question.